# SQL Server get order number

Tags: sql-server

I have table with 4 columns (`Year`, `Company`, `Document Number` and `Incoming/Outgoing`) in my SQL Server database. What I want is to get number of my 4 column.

For example if I do this:

```
Select Year, Company, Doc.Number, Incoming/Outgoing 
From table
```

Then I will get table like this:

```
Year    Company Doc.number  Incoming/Outgoing   
2015    1       1             Incoming  If this is 1 incoming
2015    1       2             Outgoing  and this is 1 Outgoing
2015    1       3             Incoming  then this is 2 Incoming
2015    1       4             Incoming  3
2015    1       5             Incoming  4
2015    1       6             Outgoing  2 Outgoing
2015    1       7             Incoming  5
2015    1       8             Outgoing  3
```

But when I do this:

```
Select Year, Company, Doc.Number, Incoming/Outgoing 
From table
Where Year = '15' and Company = '1' and doc.number = '6'
```

Then I will get this:

```
Year    Company Doc.number  Incoming/Outgoing 
2015    1       6             Outgoing
```

**EDIT**
I want to produce a 5th column containing the order number of each record within each Incoming / Outgoing partition:

```
Year    Company Doc.number  Incoming/Outgoing  Order
2015    1       6             Outgoing           2
```

Comment: So for `year='14'` you want records from 2015 (or is that a typo?),

Comment: Ok, fine - but your question is unclear. What do you mean by `I want to get order number for my 4 column`?

Comment: IMHO you need to rephrase you requirement to something like: *I want to produce a 4th column containing the order number of each record within each Incoming / Outgoing partition*.

Comment: Sorry. It is becouse my English is not to good. I want to get for this record Year ='15' and Company = '1' and doc.number = '6', a ordinal number for Outgoing. If you see hole table you will notice that for this record, a value or data  ,,Outgoing,, comes  with number 2. (Secound Outgoing)

Comment: @Nik There is a small mistake in my comment: I should have said **5th column**, since there are already 4 columns in the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to produce order numbers. Then select from `CTE`:

```
;WITH OrderCTE AS (
   SELECT [Year], [Company], [Doc.Number], [Incoming/Outgoing],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Incoming/Outgoing] ORDER BY [Doc.Number]) AS rn
   FROM [table]
)
Select [Year], [Company], [Doc.Number], [Incoming/Outgoing], rn AS [Order] 
From OrderCTE
Where Year = '2015' and Company = '1' and doc.number = '6'
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` calculates the 'order' of each record within each *Incoming* / *Outgoing* partition.

Comment: Thank you. Pozdrav iz Srbije :)